# SSH compression

Tags: ssh, compression

I want max compression on my ssh tunnel cos I'm on a dialup line ;)

At the man page can one can read:

> CompressionLevel
>                .....The meaning of the values is the same as in gzip(1).  Note that this
>                option applies to protocol version 1 only.

What if I want max compression rate and while using ssh version 2?

How know the protocol version I'm using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To know the protocol version of ssh, you can include `-v` option in your ssh command.

To request compression, you can use `-C` option. This should work even for protocol version 2.

Comment: But what about CompressionLevel option? I don't want use the default level, 6, but the 9 cos I'm over a diulup connection.

Comment: @frankabel: As I understood from the manual, you can only set the compression level for protocol version 1, but I am not sure about this.

Comment: Bad news, here http://lists.mindrot.org/pipermail/openssh-unix-dev/2003-November/019734.html I found that ssh2 is less capable than ssh1 regards compression configuration.

Comment: Seem to me that if want use max compression level (9), I must use ssh 1 instead of ssh 2

Comment: Just leave it at the default and use ssh2.  The difference isn't much, and the security gain from using v2 is worth it.

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your use case, you might want to utilize pipes in order to achieve higher compression levels for certain streams.

```
ssh ${SSH_USER}@${SSH_HOST} "
    echo 'string to be compressed' | gzip -9
" | zcat | echo -
```

The above example compresses the string/stream on the remote side (`gzip`) and decompresses it upon receipt on the local side (`zcat`).

Note that ssh's compression is **off** on intention. Only the pipe's compression is used.

You may use other compression tools like `bz2` or `xz` as well. Consider their respective performance impacts.

**NOTE:** It seems that, if the compression uses a very slow algorithm, the stream can fail to deliver in time and the connection "closes" with an error.